# Notation for block of vectors/matrices holding elements with different shapes

Tags: notation, dynamical-systems, block-matrices, robotics

I am interested in having a notation similar to block-matrix operations, where the elements of the block differ from each other, making it not truly a block-matrix.  Its best to give an example (from my application: dynamical systems).

Say we have a vector of generalized coordinates $\mathbf{q}$ for a **floating-base** robot. That means I can separate the coordinates into base configuration ---member of the special euclidean group--- $\mathbf{X}_B \in \mathcal{SE}(3)$ and joint-space $\mathbf{\hat{q}} \in \mathcal{R}^n$. I would like to define my vector of generalized coordinates in block notation $\mathbf{q} = [\mathbf{X}_B \quad \mathbf{\hat{q}}]^T$ (*Note here, mentioning the abuse of notation*), because it is in my intereset to have a notation that can allow me to decouple the operations affecting both spaces, that is, for example:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}  a_1 \cdot \mathbf{X}_B \\   \mathbf{\hat{q}} \end{bmatrix} \doteq \begin{bmatrix}  a_2 \cdot \mathbf{X}_B \\   b_2 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{q}} \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Now because the dimensions of $\mathbf{X}_B$ and $\mathbf{\hat{q}}$ differ, what is the best notation in your opinion to do as I did. Is there a better way?

Comment: I definitely don't fully understand the context, but if the things are different, what's the benefit of keeping them in the same matrix instead of an ordered pair?

Comment: Normally, the nomenclature of dynamical systems is to have a flat vector of generalized coordinates $\mathbf{q}$, flattening $\mathbf{X}$ into a position and orientation vector. So I want to keep them together because they are part of the "same" set of coordinates, but differenciate that they belong to diff spaces.

Comment: The objective of keeping them separated is to help with notation of the effects that actions of a symmetry group have on the vector of generalized coordinates. With this notation I can show that an action $g$ has one specific representation for the Euclidean Space, and one for the joint-space